# TS2339: Property 'dayjs' does not exist on type 'Cypress & EventEmitter

Tags: typescript, webstorm, cypress, dayjs

I've recently refactored my code to use dayJS rather than Moment.js, and now Webstorm is reporting a ton of TS2339 errors. These errors aren't preventing my code from compiling or running, but it is making it extremely hard to find *actual* errors. Here's an example of some code where the error shows up:

```
export function verifyCreatedDate(date: string) {
  cy.log('Verify item creation date');
  cy.get('[data-cy="timeline-date"]').should(
    'have.text',
    Cypress.dayjs(date).format('MM/DD/YY'),
  );
}
```

And here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "@percy/cypress"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "node_modules/cypress/types/mocha/index.d.ts"]
}
```

I've tried adding dayJS to both the `"types"` and `"include"` sections, then restarting WebStorm, but that didn't fix the error either. I've been searching for answers for this for about a week, and although this is a common issue, none of the proposed solutions I've found have worked.

Finally, here's the relevant portion of my `support/index.js` file:

```
// if multiple specs need to use dayjs import it in the support file
// and add to the global Cypress object
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

Cypress.dayjs = dayjs;
```

Comment: Did you try adding `d.ts` shims that add `dayjs` to `Cypress` namespace, similar to what is normally done with custom commands (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands)?

Comment: I've been looking at this, but I'm struggling to figure out how I add in dayJS. The instructions are entirely focused on adding a custom command where you define the function, how would I add a module like DayJS to the namespace using this method?

Comment: Why are you attaching dayjs to the Cypress object? Can you just import/require it in the files you need it?

Comment: We use dayJS in almost every one of our specs - The documentation recommends attaching it to the Cypress object in such a case

Answer (score 0):

`cypress/support/index.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
        ... your custom commands

    }

    import dayjs from 'dayjs';
    interface Cypress {
        dayjs: dayjs.Dayjs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what you are messing is extended types, similarly added like you do for commands: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Cypress {
    dayjs: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why using `any`? You lose all the IntelliSense stuff.

 I tried `dayjs: Dayjs;` but `import` in `suport/index.d.ts` file breaks autompletion of even previously working custom commands.